# How to define a type which can be applied on multiple parameters with different types?

Tags: typescript

I have a method called networkAction and it takes a parameter called "body". This "body" parameter should fit every body type that i'm expecting from other network calls like loginRequest, signUpRequest. These functions expecting different body types like ILogin and ISignUpPostBody.

Here is my networkAction method :

```
    public async networkAction(actionName: string, body: INetworkBody, headers?: object){

      if(this.clientNetworkCredentials){
        throw Error("Client's network credentials state is null!")
      }
        
      switch(actionName){

        case this.NHActions.LOGIN: {
          const loginResponse = await this.loginRequest(body)
          return loginResponse
        }

        case this.NHActions.SIGN_UP: {
          const signUpResponse = await this.signUpRequest(body)
          return signUpResponse
        }

        default: {
          throw Error("No Network Action recieved!")
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried defining INetworkBody as below :

```
import { ILogin, ISignUpPostBody } from "./IAuth"

export type INetworkBody = ILogin | ISignUpPostBody;
```

loginRequest and signUpRequest :

```
    public loginRequest = async (loginInfo: ILogin): Promise<IUserDbModel | null> => {

        const apiUrl = this.prepareApiUrl(this.NHActions.LOGIN)

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, loginInfo, { headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }});
            const data: IUserDbModel = response.data;
            console.log(response.data)
            return data;
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public signUpRequest = async (signUpInfo: ISignUpPostBody): Promise<IUserDbModel | null> => {

        const apiUrl = this.prepareApiUrl(this.NHActions.SIGN_UP)

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, signUpInfo, { headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }});
    
            const data: IUserDbModel = response.data;
            return response.data;
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

TypeScript has no problem with the loginRequest function body parameter but it underlines the other one red and shows there's a type conflict in signUpRequest body parameter.

Is there a way to make a type generic so it can fit in every expected type from another function parameter ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see the issue for ourselves.  This should be a single self-contained block of code that demonstrates the same basic problem, instead of an excerpt of code that leaves out necessary declarations and context.